# arcgis server 10 tif mxd problem

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, geotiff-tiff, mxd

i am using arcgis server 10. first i opened arcmap and added a.tif file. then i saved it using

```
 File ->  Save As
```

as a ArcMap Document (*.mxd) file, let's say b.mxd.

Now i open arccatalog and added arcgis server let's say "test". then by right click on this server i added new service (my b.mxd). when i press finish, it says the following:

```
 Server Object instance on machine arcgis-server is created with errors.
    The Layer: 'a.tif' in Map: 'Layers' is invalid.
 Failed to open raster dataset
```

Can you explain what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is a.tif in a folder that is accessible by Server's SOC account?

Comment: hi Kevin, a.tif is stored in C:\data1\data2\ and b.mxd is stored in C:\data1.

Comment: Do you know if the SOC account has permission to read files in c:\data1\data2? If you don't know, try moving the TIF file to c:\data1 (where the MXD is), open the MXD and point to the new location for the TIF, save the MXD and try to publish again.

Comment: hi Kevin, i put the a.tif in C:\data1 and opened it in arcmap and saved as it as b.mxd in C:\data1. i get the same error... how can i check the SOC accounts permissions?

Comment: Okay, it isn't a SOC permissions issue if the data (a.tif) and MXD were in the same location and you got that error.  I assume the TIF image looks correct in ArcMap, and coordinates are correct when you mouse-over the image?

Comment: if you use the publish toolbar in arcmap and analyze. What messages do you get?

Comment: @Kevin: hi, i did everything again by deleting all the files from inside the C:\data1 and left only the a.tif in it. and then again created b.mxd and saved it inside the C:\data1, and everything worked fine. thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Brad: i already forgot, but i think it was some kind of error...

Comment: if you use the analyze button there are differing level messages alert, warning, and errors. alerts and warnings will probably still publish successfully. Errors will not.

Comment: ArcGIS 10.0 sometimes has problems with .tif files. Try installing the latest service pack.

Answer (score 1):

You should examine the msd option when creating services.
Probably would be a big benefit for documents with images also.
Here are some links that might help.

[ESRI Web Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sq00000018000000.htm) has pointers for creating effective services
[ESRI Web Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000034000000.htm) also has some python code for working with msd files
Derek Law has [some links here](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=1696&t=297330)